# (Android SDk 2.1) Getting error when I use setAudioSource and setVideoSource

Tags: android, video, audio, sdk

I got the follow error when I run setAudioSource and setVideoSource.

03-16 10:26:25.302: ERROR/audio_input(52): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value

03-16 10:26:25.302: ERROR/audio_input(52): VerifyAndSetParameter failed

03-16 10:26:25.302: ERROR/CameraInput(52): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)

03-16 10:26:25.302: ERROR/CameraInput(52): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0

This error happen on both emulator and the device. (I am using Google nexus one)

I have set the CAMERA and RECORD_AUDIO user permission already. I spent many days but I still cannot figure out what is the cause of this runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably requesting camera and/or sound input parameters that the system doesn't support. You can use [`Camera.Parameters.getSupportedXX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) functions to query for supported parameters.

Comment: Thx Roman, I just used the sample code from google website. I didn't request any special functions from Camera.

How about the error of setAudioSource ? Is it the same cause ?  It seems so complicated to correctly setup the camera and audio recorder.

Comment: Can you link to the exact sample code you're using (I'm guessing something in `ApiDemos`?). Also, which device and OS version are you testing on?