# setVideoSource throwing RunTimeException (was: IllegalStateException)

Tags: java, android, android-camera

When I call **setVideoSource** on a **MediaRecorder** object, it throws an **IllegalStateException**. I've checked these:

[(Android SDk 2.1) Getting error when I use setAudioSource and setVideoSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451763/android-sdk-2-1-getting-error-when-i-use-setaudiosource-and-setvideosource)

[Why following code shows setVideoSource failed exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164138/why-following-code-shows-)
setvideosource-failed-exception

[MediaPlayer.prepare() throws IllegalStateException on Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189539/mediaplayer-prepare-throws-illegalstateexception-on-android-l)

But the solutions suggested have either not helped or been inappropriate.

The code looks like:

```
private void initRecorder() {
    Log.i(TAG, "InitRecorder");
    if(mRecorder == null) {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
        mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        mRecorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/video.mp4");
        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
        mRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    }
}
```

I'm certain that setOutputFormat is not being called before setVideoSource, the correct permissions are being requested and granted, and there is just one VideoRecorder object in existence.

I'm using Android SDK 23 on a Moto G with Marshmallow installed.

Does anyone have any ideas? It would be useful to get more information from the exception but somehow Android Studio won't let me get at it. I guess a related question would be how can I examine an exception at the point it is thrown? Is it likely to contain more information than just the fact that it is an IllegalStateException?

The exception has now changed to a **RunTimeException**, which is confusing. I've backed out any changes I made to it so it should be throwing the IllegalStateException but it's pretty much stuck on the RunTimeException now. Hmm...

Here is the error log:

```
06-28 13:10:14.989 30933-30933/com.dogtail W/ActivityThread: Application com.dogtail is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-28 13:10:14.990 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
06-28 13:10:15.142 30933-30939/com.dogtail I/art: Debugger is active
06-28 13:10:15.190 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: Debugger has connected
06-28 13:10:15.191 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-28 13:10:15.391 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-28 13:10:15.591 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-28 13:10:15.791 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-28 13:10:15.992 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-28 13:10:16.192 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-28 13:10:16.392 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-28 13:10:16.592 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/System.out: debugger has settled (1312)
06-28 13:10:16.636 30933-30933/com.dogtail W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dogtail-1/lib/arm
06-28 13:10:17.599 30933-30933/com.dogtail W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dogtail-1/lib/arm
06-28 13:10:17.681 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/APPLICATION: onCreate
06-28 13:10:17.934 30933-31061/com.dogtail I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/09/15, 6cbbf7d, I3193f6e94a
06-28 13:10:17.936 30933-31061/com.dogtail I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-28 13:10:20.588 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/VideoRecorder: OnCreate
06-28 13:10:20.588 30933-30933/com.dogtail I/VideoRecorder: InitRecorder
06-28 13:10:20.598 30933-30933/com.dogtail E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.dogtail, PID: 30933
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dogtail/com.dogtail.VideoRecorder}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setVideoSource failed.
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setVideoSource failed.
                                                                 at android.media.MediaRecorder.setVideoSource(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.dogtail.VideoRecorder.initRecorder(VideoRecorder.java:45)
                                                                 at com.dogtail.VideoRecorder.onCreate(VideoRecorder.java:30)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: please add your error log

Answer (score 0):

You are using setOutputFormat and setProfile both.

Remove following line

> mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);.

And error go away

You should also remove lines

> mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
>           mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

Because mRecorder.setProfile(cpHigh); already added these property by default.

Comment: the exception is being thrown on the setVideoSource line which is before the setOutputFormat, so I don't think that's it...

Comment: setOutputFormat property added twice, setProfile also added this property. android media framework is not too smart

Comment: but the exception is being thrown before setOutputFormat is called at all?

Comment: I removed the call to setOutputFormat, and the RunTimeException is still thrown

Comment: Aha! It was permissions, sorry, The permissions.CAMERA was deleted from the permissions list by mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was permissions, not duplicate calls to setOutputFormat, but thanks anyway.